# Plot Frequency density underestimated by trapz(x,f)

Tags: matlab, plot

I'd like to plot a frequency density diagram from a data set below, with bin width=10 units:

`[f x]=hist(p,1:10:200);
    bar(x,f/trapz(x,f));`

However `sum(10*f)/trapz(x,f)=1.0461`. Shouldn't the area calculated by `trapz`=1?

[image]

```
`p=[23.7648
40.5013
34.7466
24.8569
68.2174
40.8811
78.1818
18.6804
22.3158
80.4086
15.0927
44.1342
163.6714
6.4450
22.9075
17.5615
8.8536
26.3300
32.6789
42.4225
22.3832
3.0519
16.6581
32.9496
10.3606]`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trapz` is an integral calculation which reconstructs a signal via [first-order hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_hold) whereas `sum(10*f)` uses [zero-order hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold). That's why your ratio isn't 1. For more info, you can also check out [Orders of approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_approximation).

Comment: I understand that being a quadrature formula it is an approximation however I note that matlab's own `dfittool` does makes a better approximation than `trapz`.  Do you recommend against using `trapz` for this purpose?

Comment: when I need to normalize my histogram I use `sum`. Recommend vs not depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Also note that the error is less then 5%, which is peanuts for most people

Comment: Surely `Sum` works only for bins with sum equal to 1?  Perhaps I should rephrase my question better: What does matlab use in `dfittool` that is more accurate than `trapz`?